# Corrupted stack/heap under debugger when simulating?

Tags: xcode, debugging, xcode6, ios-simulator, breakpoints

I'm using Xcode 6.3.1. I'm trying to track a weird issue in an app and now I'm seeing that local variables seem to be incorrectly initialised. When I hit a breakpoint at the line where a local variable is defined and initialised at the same time, it is actually shown as an existing local variable, but with a corrupt value:

[image: corrupt initial value for xview local variable - which shouldn't be defined yet]

Has anyone else seen this? In another run the variable was actually showing in the variable view as being an NSDate !!!

Answer (score 3):

A breakpoint is actually before the line it appears on; that line has not yet executed. You are thus looking too soon at this variable. It has no meaningful value until *after* you step *past* the line where it is initialized. You are still before that line so its value is random garbage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that prior to that XCode update I wouldn't see the variable at all - which would make sense according to your comment , as the debugger stops before the line is being executed, and thus the local variable hasn't even been defined yet (i.e. is not yet in scope).

Comment: OK, just tried with XCode 6.2, me issue, and the debugger shows the variable the same way too. Totally stumped now...

Comment: "and thus the local variable hasn't even been defined yet (i.e. is not yet in scope)" That isn't actually how C works. Remember back when C required that all declarations take place _before_ all executable statements? The compiler is still doing that behind the scenes. So all locals are in fact declared (i.e. storage is set aside) as soon as the function starts, and the debugger reveals that fact. But locals are not meaningfully _initialized_ until the line pointer is _after_ the line where initialization takes place.

Comment: Yep.  It's more efficient to allocate stack space all at once for the multiple variables, so you're just seeing side-effects of that.  This is behaving exactly as it should be.  One could imagine an optimization whereby the debugger knew that the variable was not yet declared and thus hid the data from the developer, but IMO developer tools should focus on showing data rather than hiding it when possible =).