# In swift, why true && false = 16?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

[image: when I exec the code, the c = 16, why ?]

I have seen the Swift spec, it says

> The logical AND operator (`a && b`) creates logical expressions where
>   both values must be true for the overall expression to also be true.

If either value is false, the overall expression will also be false. In fact, if the first value is false, the second value won’t even be evaluated, because it can’t possibly make the overall expression equate to true. This is known as short-circuit evaluation.

This example considers two Bool values and only allows access if both values are true:

```
let enteredDoorCode = true
let passedRetinaScan = false
if enteredDoorCode && passedRetinaScan {
    println("Welcome!")
} else {
    println("ACCESS DENIED")
}
// prints "ACCESS DENIED"
```

It has nothing about this problem, is this a bug ?

Comment: You haven't executed that line yet, so `c` is undefined. Step to the next line and then it should be correct.

Comment: Normally, the highlighted line is the line *not executed yet*. Have you tried stepping to the next line, so the `&&` actually gets executed?

Answer (score 5):

You probably hit the breakpoint **before** this line was actually evaluated (at least your screenshot suggests so). Go one step further down and you'll see `c` become `false` as expected.

At this point in time, `c` only points to a *random location in memory* which happens to be interpreted as `16` by the debugger.

Comment: You beat me to it by 30 seconds or so.

Comment: haha sorry dude, take my upvote though!

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> var c = a && b
> ```

The breakpoint is at the statement. The statement has not executed. You are seeing garbage.

Also see [Corrupted stack/heap under debugger when simulating?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29863431).